# How can i enable and disable NETWORK_PROVIDER programatically

Tags: android, gps

We all know about that GPS Issues on Android.

How do we create the same turnOnGps Function Bellow to a NETWORK_PROVIDER, I want turn on Both.

```
private void turnGPSOn(){   

String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);   
if(!provider.contains("gps")){      
    final Intent poke = new Intent();  
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");           poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);   
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));      
    sendBroadcast(poke);  
}  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just adding onto what CommonsWare mentioned, that method only works on Android versions of 2.2 and below.

However, you can use the, simple, code below:

```
startActivity(new Intent("android.settings.LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS"));
```

This will take the user directly to the screen where they can enable/disable Location based options.

Refer [here (docs)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html), for more settings

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the Help. But i would like to do this in code, without the user. Any other Idea?

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's the only way to do it, as far as I know, the code you provided was just a little hack -thing- that was a bug in the `PowerManager` but was fixed on 2.3+, like CommonsWare said, "You cannot enable or disable any location provider yourself, for blindingly obvious privacy reasons." It will require user interaction, because it's the user's choice to have GPS enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, the script-kiddie technique you cite above does not work on modern versions of Android. You cannot enable or disable any location provider yourself, for blindingly obvious privacy reasons. Please allow the user to enable or disable location providers through the OS-supplied mechanisms (Settings, Power Control app widget, etc.).